# How can I get the 2nd element of each subset without using a loop - python

Tags: python

I have an input:

```
temp = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
```

and I want the output as:

```
[2,4,6]
```

How can I do that **without** using a loop in **python**?

Is there something like temp[:][1]?  (i.e. for all the subsets take the 2nd element)

**Please note:** This is an example data. I need to do this for a much bigger dataset. So an implementation with good performance will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `numpy`. `numpy` is very powerful and efficient for manipulating array or matrix. a [tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html) goes here.

```
import numpy

temp = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
arr = numpy.array(temp)
print(arr[:,1])  
# array([2, 4, 6])

# convert back to list
l = list(arr[:,1])
print(l)
# [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Numpy is probably overkill for this.

Comment: yeah.. i know, but i think OP may do some more array manipulation when he/she finished element selection, so numpy is a good tool if OP would like to extends more. anyway it is beyond the scope of this post...

Comment: I had to convert it into numpy eventually.. So went with this approach. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Just zip the lists together.

```
temp = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
a = list(zip(*temp))[1]
print(a)
```

**output**

```
(2, 4, 6)
```

If the output must be a list:

```
print(list(a))
```

**output**

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

---

The above code is for Python 3, where `zip` returns an iterator. In Python 2 it's slightly simpler, since `zip` returns a list.

```
temp = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
print list(zip(*temp)[1])
```

**output**

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it via. *list slicing*. Here, you can use a *list comprehension* expression as (*suggested approach*):

```
>>> temp = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
>>> [t[1] for t in temp]
[2, 4, 6]
```

---

For achieving it without *explicit for loop*, you may use `map()` with `operator.itemgetter()` as:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list(map(itemgetter(1), temp))
[2, 4, 6]
```

Even though you do not see *loop* explicitly visible here, but internally it makes a call to the loop. There is no way to achieve this without loop.

Comment: OP asked for without using a loop

Comment: @FallAndLearn: Updated the answer, but there is no way to do it without loop. You have to make a *loop* call either implicitly or explicitly

Comment: Yes. Correct. It was a silly question altogether. Map will also iterate internally.

Comment: FWIW, using `map` with `itemgetter(1)` is faster than `map` with `lambda x: x[1]`. But using `zip` is even better because then everything in the implicit loop can happen at C speed whereas `map` is performing a Python function call on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply go trough the list and create a new list like this:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
l = [i[1] for i in a]
```

l holds your desired values now.

Best of Luck!

[**edit:** like other answers indicated, even if there is no explicitly visible loop, there will be an internal loop. Another option is to use numpy and slices.]

Answer (score 0):

This is withour a loop:

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]

items = list(map(lambda x: x[1], a))

print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

1st chaining the nested list using chain from itertools, then access the flatten list with indexing

```
from itertools import chain, islice
temp = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
temp_flatten = list(chain.from_iterable(temp))
# temp_flatten = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

# access with indexing
>>> temp_flatten[1::2] 
[2, 4, 6]
```

Or even better to do it 1 shot using chain and islice

```
from itertools import chain, islice
temp = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
list(islice(chain.from_iterable(temp), 1, None, 2))
# [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Since you're importing `itertools` anyway, you might as well do the slicing _before_ building the list: `list(islice(chain.from_iterable(temp), 1, None, 2))`